# Qt errors after static compilation

Tags: qt, compilation, static-libraries

I'm writing a Qt program with Qt creator (v2.5.0 
Based on Qt 4.8.1 (64 bit)) on a computer under Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. It works fine on my computer and I'm happy about it.

But now I want to deploy my app, so I decided to try to do build my project statically. In order to do that, I compiled Qt statically (from the 4.8.3 sources), I changed the qmake choice in Qt creator (replaced it with the "static" one), and I selected "static build" in build settings.

At first it seemed to work perfectly: my new executable file was 15Mb (instead of its usual 1Mb) and when I did ldd ./myApp to check the dependencies, there were no more libQtGui.so.4 nor libQtCore.so.4, and the program seemed to work okay.

Then I realized Qt Creator was constantly yelling in the Application output:

**"Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed"**

That can't be too good, what's going on? Worse, when I try to load the help menu of my program, somehow it doesn't manage to open the window and sort of freezes. The help menu is just a widget containing a QTextBrowser (which displays an html file with a couple png pics) and a few buttons. I get the following error repeatedly in the app output:

****X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x0****

and one (or more?) **QNativeImage: Unable to attach to shared memory segment.**

It might have something to do with the fact that when I added the static version of qmake (in Qt options, Build & Run, Qt versions tab), I get the warning:
"No qmlviewer installed". I have no idea.

Anyway, I'm kind of disappointed and depressed, deploying the app is much harder than I expected and incredibly annoying. Does anyone know how to fix this?

While I'm here, I have a few other small questions:

1. Does it matter that Qt creator does `qmake myApp.pro -r -spec linux-g++` and `make -w` instead of just `qmake` and `make`?
2. I read in several places to add LIBS in my .pro file, also I read in one place I should write CONFIG += static, Qt official doc says to do things slightly differently (but for once, I find it **very** badly written and confusing), but all of this doesn't seem to do anything. Does it matter?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: CONFIG += static is for producing static libraries. It's described in documentation http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#config

Answer (score 1):

> It might have something to do with the fact that when I added the static version of qmake (in Qt options, Build & Run, Qt versions tab), I get the warning: "No qmlviewer installed". I have no idea.

It has nothing to do with adding the static version of qmake and getting the warning "No qmlviewer installed" is normal

> Does it matter that Qt creator does qmake myApp.pro -r -spec linux-g++ and make -w instead of just qmake and make?

No, its fine

> I read in several places to add LIBS in my .pro file, also I read in one place I should write CONFIG += static, Qt official doc says to do things slightly differently (but for once, I find it very badly written and confusing), but all of this doesn't seem to do anything. Does it matter?

I usually compile my project with 
`CONFIG +=static\ release`

And you have to add `LIBS+=` to your project only if your loading any dynamic library files or other library files which are not in the system path.

Answer (score 1):

```
Warning: X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)
```

is a known problem for Qt apps

http://www.iwillfolo.com/quick-fix-one-kdes-common-xorg-errors-x-error-baddrawable/

it is fixed using

```
export QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
```

or

```
QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 yourapp
```

> QT_X11_NO_MITSHM – stops Qt form using the MIT-SHM X11 extension.

More info here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT-SHM